# Pry in Emacs "Completion aborted: Not at a top-level prompt"

Tags: emacs, pry

I have set up an environment for using pry in Emacs (emacsclient), but the completion function is not wokrking and get this message: "Completion aborted: Not at a top-level prompt".

Has anyone solved this problem?

.emacs.el
(require 'inf-ruby)
(setq inf-ruby-default-implementation "pry")
(add-to-list 'inf-ruby-implementations '("pry" . "pry"))
(setq inf-ruby-eval-binding "Pry.toplevel_binding")

Emacs version: 24.3

Pry version 0.10.1 on Ruby 2.1.2

Comment: You haven't mentioned the version of inf-ruby you have installed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! It's inf-ruby-20141005.550, which was downloaded using MELPA. And the OS is Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt may indeed be not a the top level (if it's a continuation prompt). Then finish the expression (without leaving any unclosed parens, etc) press `RET` and try again.

If you always get this message when trying to complete, file an issue. Include your version of inf-ruby, your OS details, and the contents of the inf-ruby buffer, including the prompts.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Dmitry. Yes I always get this message.

Comment: You mean filing an issue to the emacs community? I'd be glad if you tell me how, since I'm not familiar with it..